# NetApp NFS Exports with all_squash

Tags: nfs, netapp

We've got a NetApp filer (v8.1.4) with a UNIX-style qtree sharing a volume to a number of different machines (web content for a cluster of front-end and application servers) over NFS.  We're trying to figure out a way to use `all_squash` (with `anonuid/anogid`) to force all clients to read/write using the same UID/GID.  This will allow the application/www servers to read and write files without needing to chown/chmod every file after it is created.

NetApp doesn't seem to like `all_squash`, and I can't find any way to do this on the client-side across several machines (a mix of Ubuntu, OS X, etc.).

My only final recourse is to set up a polling task that looks for fs changes and resets uid/gid and a+r every time a file is created or the owner is changed.

Is there any way to enforce uid/gid on the NetApp side that I'm missing?

Comment: A long-term solution is to ensure that user IDs are consistent across all your machines by joining them to a domain (e.g. with FreeIPA).

Comment: Agreed, we have investigated this (likely AD/LDAP) but it isn't a good solution in the short-term.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this from experience, but I've started looking for one here: https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1366835/html/index.html

Comment: Oh, I was assuming this was clustered data ontap. Is that true? Or is this 7-mode?